# Change css properties for pre-written classes

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net

I have a bunch of css classes with respective css properties which I am using for my web page. My question is, can I change the css properties of those classes as those classes are being used in other web forms as well?Does it affect all the other forms if I change any css proeprty in any of the css class?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you going to change the CSS? using a JQuery for example? Are you going to change the CSS for the active page you are in only?

Comment: Yes, that's a good question. I thought you were just talking about changing the CSS page manually. Are you referring to changing it on the fly, like, as Moe said, using scripting?

Comment: Ok, so I am replicating a page as it is and the original page creator transferred few style sheets to me that has all relative classes. I am not creating a stylesheet my web page instead I am making everything inline, copy pasting the styles from that whole bunch. Within the inline style I am trying to make little changes.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the css in an external css file will most likely change the forms on the other pages, too, provided they are linked to that css file and are using that same class to get their stylings.

That’s sort of the idea behind it, where normally people want to make changes “across the board” by changing the CSS sheet only. I wasn’t sure from your comment if this was desirable or not in your case.

Did you want to change just one form, without affecting the others?